# Series and Numerical Solution of Second Order Boundary Value Problem using Mathematica

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear

I am just a toddler in Mathematica, please help me in finding the numerical and series solution of the following boundary value problem:

- u''[t] == - A u[t]^4,
  u[0]==1, u[1]==1,

where A lies in between 0 and 1

The graphs as well.

Comment: You can not get a numerical solution if "A" is symbolic.

Answer (score 3):

For numerical DSolve, you can use `ParametricNDSolve`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Code

```
ode = u''[t] + a*u[t]^4 == 0
ic = {u[0] == 1, u[1] == 1}
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{ode, ic}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {a}]
data = Flatten@
   Last@Reap@
     Do[p = Plot[Evaluate[u[a][t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1}, 
        AxesLabel -> {"t", "u[t]"}, 
        PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.8, 1.2}}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
        GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray];
      Sow[Labeled[p, Row[{"a=", a}]]], {a, 0, 1, .1}];
Grid[Partition[data, 3], Spacings -> 5, Frame -> All]
```

For series solution use `AsymptoticDSolveValue`. Mathematica can solve this but without the IC. Here is 6 terms series expansion around zero

```
ode = u''[t] + a*u[t]^4 == 0
ic = {u[0] == 1, u[1] == 1}
sol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode, u, {t, 0, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when adding the IC, it could not find the series. Maybe because you have BVP and not initial value ode. Normally series solution of ode's is for initial value problems.

Answer (score 2):

OP did not specify what they meant by "series solution" but a natural (and, in practice, very useful) series solution is a power series in $A$ (which is expected to work very well since $A\in(0,1)$). This series solution is easy to find, we just let
$$
u(t)=\sum_{k\ge0}u_k(t)A^k
$$
and solve iteratively in $k$. For example for $A=0$ the equation is $u''(t)=0$ with boundary values $u(0)=u(1)=1$, namely $u_0(t)=1$. The next few orders are given by
$$
u(t)=1-\frac{1}{2} A t(t-1)+\frac{1}{6} A^2t (t^3-2 t^2+1)+\frac{1}{360} A^3t (-26 t^5+78 t^4-45 t^3-40 t^2+33)+\frac{1}{720} A^4 t (23 t^7-92 t^6+96 t^5+34 t^4-60 t^3-44 t^2+43)+\mathcal O(A^5)
$$

This approximation is actually very close to the actual result, as computed by Nasser:

[image]

As expected, the solution gets worse and worse for higher $A$, since the higher order corrections become more and more important. These higher orders are very easy to add, if one wishes to.